# MongoEngine: How to add EmbeddedDocument and its container list at same time?

Tags: mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a working db that needs a list of EmbeddedDocuments added to a model.

```
class Alert(medb.EmbeddedDocument):
    # embedded in Sensor
    name = medb.StringField(default='new alert')
    destination_list = medb.ListField(medb.EmbeddedDocumentField(AlarmDestination))
```

but, when I try to add the first AlarmDestination with:

```
        dest = models.AlarmDestination()
        dest.notifydestination_id = ObjectId(post['id'])
        alertdata.destination_list.append(dest)
        thesite.save()
```

I get the following error:

*Updating the path 'sensordict.4.alert_list.1.destination_list.0.notifydestination_id' would create a conflict at 'sensordict.4.alert_list.1.destination_list')*

A little fumbling around revealed the problem appears to be that since this is a change to the model, the destination_list does not exist yet when trying to saving the first new AlarmDestination.
If I manually add an empty Destination_list(array) with Mongo Compass and run my code again it works fine.

How can I ensure my code will always work even if the container for my new EmbeddedField does not yet exist?